# Problem creating table with SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My create table statement looks like this:

```
private static final String USER_CREATE =
 "create table user (uid text unique, pw text, admin integer);";
```

When I try to insert into the db, it lets me insert a value for uid, but if I try to insert a value for pw or admin, it throws a SQLiteException 'table user has no column named pw', and the same for admin. Is my syntax not right? Here's my DBAdapter code:

```
public class DBAdapter extends Activity {
```

//****************DATABASE CONSTANTS*********************

public static final String WORDS_TABLE = "words";
 public static final String ATT_WORD = "word";
    public static final String ATT_T1 = "T1";
    public static final String ATT_T2 = "T2";
    public static final String ATT_T3 = "T3";
    public static final String ATT_T4 = "T4";
    public static final String ATT_T5 = "T5";
    public static final String ATT_RECENT = "recent";
    public static final String ATT_RATING = "rating";

```
public static final String STATISTICS_TABLE = "statistics";
public static final String ATT_GAMESPLAYED = "gamesPlayed";
public static final String ATT_wordsCORRECT = "wordsCorrect";
public static final String ATT_wordsWRONG = "wordsWrong";
public static final String ATT_POINTTOTAL = "pointTotal";
public static final String ATT_WINS = "wins";
public static final String ATT_LOSSES = "losses";

public static final String SETTING_TABLE = "settings";
public static final String ATT_SID = "sid";
public static final String ATT_TYPE = "type";
public static final String ATT_DURATION = "duration";
public static final String ATT_PTSTOWIN = "ptsToWin";

public static final String CATEGORIES_TABLE = "categories";
public static final String ATT_CATEGORY = "category";

public static final String BELONGS_TABLE = "belongs";

public static final String USER_TABLE = "user";
public static final String ATT_UID = "uid";
public static final String ATT_PW = "pw";
public static final String ATT_ADMIN = "admin";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "taboo";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String WORDS_CREATE =
    "create table words (_id primary key autoincrement,word text,"
    + "T1 text,T2 text,T3 text,T4 text,T5 text,"
    + "recent integer,rating integer);";

private static final String CATEGORIES_CREATE =
    "create table categories (_id integer primary key autoincrement,category text unique);";

private static final String BELONGS_CREATE =  
 "create table belongs (_id integer primary key autoincrement,word text,category text,"
    + "foreign key (word) references words (word),foreign key (category) references categories (category));";

private static final String USER_CREATE =
 "create table user (uid text unique, pw text, admin integer);";

private static final String STATISTICS_CREATE =   
    "create table statistics (_id integer primary key  autoincrement, uid text unique, gamesPlayed integer, wordsCorrect integer, "
    +"wordsWrong integer, pointTotal integer, wins integer, losses integer, "
    +"foreign key (uid) references user (uid));";

private static final String SETTINGS_CREATE =
    "create table settings (_id integer primary key autoincrement, uid text, sid text, "
    +"type text, duration integer, ptsToWin integer, "
    +"foreign key (uid) references user (uid));"
    ;


//**************************************************************
//*********************  Function Constants ********************
//**************************************************************

private final Context context; 
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
public static SQLiteDatabase db;
private int wordCount = 100;

//********************  Object 
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
 DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(WORDS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(CATEGORIES_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(BELONGS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(USER_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(STATISTICS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(SETTINGS_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
                          int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
              + " to "
              + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + WORDS_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

//****************************************************
//********  Database Functions  **********************
//****************************************************

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
 db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
} 
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
```

And my insert code:

```
public long enterUser(ContentValues content)
{
 long result = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, content);
 return result;
}
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run your SQL manaully?

Comment: where is the code that sets up the ContextValues?

Comment: It creates the table fine, and the insert seems to work as well

Comment: Aaron - ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
             content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_UID, (user.getText()).toString());
             content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_PW, (pw.getText()).toString());
             content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_ADMIN, admins.toString());

Comment: ERROR/Database(1315): Error inserting uid=meburbo pw=thirty3 admin=0
ERROR/Database(1315): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named pw: , while compiling: INSERT INTO user(uid, pw, admin) VALUES(?, ?, ?);

Comment: Can you show us an example of your insert commands?

Answer (score 1):

DATABASE_NAME = "taboo" needed to be "taboo.db"